# How to make boundary of x and y points using turtle in Python

Tags: python, csv, turtle-graphics

I want to ask about turtle library in Python.

I have a `CSV` file with more than a thousand x and y coordinates in decimal form.

I have been trying to draw a boundary out of it. It would be better if someone guide me on this.

```
x,y

74.741996766068,37.0220565806516

74.7491989145055,37.0214805616257

74.7692108154297,37.0256614702854

74.7718505859375,37.0269050617947

74.7776947040111,37.0296592720303

74.7827606210485,37.0320396441619
```

So for I have written this below code but it didn't get work for me.

```
import turtle

import csv

import sys

def main():

    daniel = turtle.Turtle()    #Set up a turtle named "daniel"

    myWin = turtle.Screen()     #The graphics window

    t = open('CSV.csv')

    #Draw a square

    for i in t:
        daniel.forward(t[1])     #Move forward 10 steps

        daniel.right(t[0])        #Turn 90 degrees to the right


    myWin.exitonclick()         #Close the window when clicked

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You took some turtle code that simply draws a square, imported a csv reader module but didn't use it, randomly modified the code and are now frustrated that it doesn't work.  Let's try to do better:

```
import turtle
import csv

daniel = turtle.Turtle()  # Set up a turtle named "daniel"
daniel.penup()

with open('CSV.csv', newline='') as t:
    next(t)  # skip over column descriptions

    reader = csv.reader(t, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)  # turn unquoted values into floats

    for x, y in reader:
        daniel.goto(x, y)
        daniel.pendown()  # no-op after 1st iteration


myWin = turtle.Screen()  # The graphics window

myWin.exitonclick()  # Close the window when clicked
```

This assumes your `CVS.cvs` data is single spaced, not double spaced as you presented it:

```
x,y
74.741996766068,37.0220565806516
74.7491989145055,37.0214805616257
74.7692108154297,37.0256614702854
74.7718505859375,37.0269050617947
74.7776947040111,37.0296592720303
74.7827606210485,37.0320396441619
```

This data will not draw anything as your points are effectively all the same since they are so close together -- you may need to scale your data, or use more/different data to see any actual drawing.

Comment: Yes. It is now working and I understood the code. Now a different issue, although it draws the polygon boundary but the screen is very small like I merely see the drawing.

Comment: @AAA, I don't understand your additional issue.  Perhaps you can provide a link to your entire set of a thousand points so I can see what you're seeing.  Also consider if it's a completely unrelated question and worthy of its own SO post.